# Increase the precision of the values returned by the heart beat sensor on a Tizen device

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, ros, tizen

what i want to achieve, is try to increase the precison of the values returned by the heart beat sensor of a Tizen smartwatch.
The values are Float64 numbers, since the language is Javascript.
I tried to use a function like this:

```
function strip(interval) {
return (parseFloat(interval).toPrecision(4));
}
```

but with no success. Maybe i'm doing something wrong, like doing some programming mistakes, i really don't know. Apparently, the IDE compile and build the package to install with no problem, but i can't see something different with or without this function included.
I will post my entire code below. Please check when is created the function `strip` . I've used the escamotage `if (interval !== 0) {
   interval_screen = interval;
   }` because i don't want the zeros to be printed. Please note that i want the variable streamed to the ROS topic HeartRateInterval to remain a Float; this is why i've also used the parseFloat function.
Thank you!
Code :

```
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
    if(e.keyName === "back")
        window.webapis.motion.stop("HRM");
        tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
});

function Connect(){

var ip;
var connection=false;
var interval_screen = 0;
if (document.getElementById("ip").value==="")
{ 
    ip="10.42.0.1";
}
else 
{ 
    ip=document.getElementById("ip").value;
}

var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
    url : 'ws://' + ip +':9090'
    });

ros.on('connection', function() {
    connection=true;
    document.getElementById("Connection_status").setAttribute("color","green");
    document.getElementById("Connection_status").innerHTML = 'Connected';
    tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_DIM");
});

ros.on('error', function(error) {
    document.getElementById("Connection_status").setAttribute("color","orange");
    document.getElementById("Connection_status").innerHTML = 'Error';
});

ros.on('close', function() {
    document.getElementById("Connection_status").setAttribute("color","red");
    document.getElementById("Connection_status").innerHTML = 'Unconnected';
    connection=false;
    tizen.power.release("SCREEN");
});

    var RatePub = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/HeartRateData',
    messageType : 'std_msgs/Float64'
});

var IntervalPub = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/HeartRateInterval',
    messageType : 'std_msgs/Float64'
});

window.webapis.motion.start("HRM", onchangedCB);

function onchangedCB(hrmInfo)
{
   var rate = hrmInfo.heartRate;
   document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = 'Heart Rate= ' + rate + ' bpm';

   var interval = hrmInfo.rRInterval/1000;
   function strip(interval) {
   return (parseFloat(interval).toPrecision(4));
   }
   if (interval !== 0) {
   interval_screen = interval;
   }
   document.getElementById("mytext1").innerHTML = 'RR Interval= ' + interval_screen + ' s';

   var Float64 = new ROSLIB.Message({
            data:rate
        });

        if(connection===true)
            {
            RatePub.publish(Float64);
            }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = 'Heart Rate = 0 bpm';
        }

   var Float64 = new ROSLIB.Message({
            data:interval
        });

        if(connection===true)
            { if (interval !== 0) {
            IntervalPub.publish(Float64);
            }
            else {

            }
            }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("mytext1").innerHTML = 'RR Interval = 0 s';
        }

        }}
```

Comment: I tried to use `interval.toPrecision(4);` directly after `var interval = hrmInfo.rRInterval/1000;` but nothing has changed. I tried also `parseFloat(interval).toPrecision(4);` with the same result. @RC NL

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here, but I can not find where you actually call that new function?
And why do you create it inline inside the onchangedCB function?

It looks as if you expected that function to be called because you declare it there and call the parameter the same as the interval variable. Which will not work (as far as I know in any programming language).

Then what I would try is call that function parseFloat(interval).toPrecision
directly instead of putting it in another function.

But what I'm far more interested in is:
here hrmInfo.rRInterval/1000
the orginal value is devived by a thousand.

Remove that division (like this var interval = hrmInfo.rRInterval;) and see if there actually are more numbers where the decimal point would be.

I can not make it up from your example, but if the value normally is something like 120 per minute. And you want to know if there are more precise values behind that, then the value should now look something like 1200054 if it is all zeroes like 120000 all the time, then the systems creating that event does not give off a more precise measure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, in fact it isn't called. And of course this is one of the error. I will try to call it directly. I need that division because it's not the heart beat per minute (bpm) but the time between two succesive beats. And, since the sensor gives values in milliseconds, but i need them in seconds, i must divide them.

Comment: hello, do you think that is possible that the precision of the sensor cannot be increased? I have also a strange behavior of the data that are coming from the sensor; it seems that only even values are printed and i don't know why.

Comment: Could be, hard to say without logging and digging through the data.
If I combine the information you provided regarding this device and the code.
Saying: the on onchangedCB is triggered to provide an update on the heart rate and the hrmInfo.heartRate is already the heart rate normalized to BPM then maybe the hrmInfo.rRInterval will not help you unless you know what was actually measured between those intervals. 
If you want to 'improve' the reading you need 2 variables that could lead to that BPM. (Interval + beats this interval) multiplied bij the number of intervals that fit in a minute.

Comment: The alternative could be, you take the BPM and BPM difference between 2 or more intervals. Normalise that data to figure out what that value means on a shorter amount of time (BPS or beat per interval for example). And translate that back to the value you want (the BPM with decimals or ms between beats for example).
This will not work however if the event is not called less then once a minute.

So I would go and try to figure out which variables are available in total. Get some test data, put it in Excel or on paper and do some manual math to figure out what you can achieve.

Comment: I'm afraid that i didn't understand the first of the new comments that you made. I mean, i already have the two type of data that can be achieved by this device. The hrmInfo.heartRate and the hrmInfo.rRInterval are the BPM and the time that flows between two next heart beats, respectively. I can say so from the Tizen wiki of the developer website. And this is how you must call these data, because they depend on the hardware and on the IDE syntax. Maybe i misunderstood your comments. Thank you!